# Is it possible to specify the string "User" in the mention banner?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to specify the string "User" in the banner notification that I receive when I send a message via the connector?

The code of the message you are sending is:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "<at>mentioned</at>, Hello! World",
            "wrap": true
          }
        ],
        "actions": [
          {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "url": "https://www.example.com",
            "title": "Open Url"
          }
        ],
        "msteams": {
          "entities": [
            {
              "type": "mention",
              "text": "<at>mentioned</at>",
              "mentioned": {
                "id": "naoto.omori@msandc.co.jp",
                "name": "Naoto Omori"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[banner of mention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO62R.png)

Comment: Shall you want like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT2hv.png or could you please share the repro steps so we can try it from our end?

Comment: No.This banner is displayed when you POST the above json to the URL of the connector.

Comment: It's not possible to do this. specify the string "User" in the banner notification.
Could you please raise a user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this. specify the string "User" in the banner notification. Could you please raise a user voice here: [microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)